# How to Download a file when pressing a button in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, download

Iam creating a web site using flutter. i need to download a pdf file when pressing a button. How can i implement this downloading file functionality in flutter web.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find your answer here. (Potential Duplicate)

[Flutter WEB download option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783344/flutter-web-download-option)