# Flutter web: Download large files by reading a stream from the server?

Tags: download, flutter-web

There are already several articles about starting downloads from flutter web.
I link this answer as example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075629/15537341

The procedure is always similar: Request something from a server, maybe convert the body bytes to base64 and than use the AnchorElement to start the download.
It works perfectly for small files. Let's say, 30MB, no problem.
The whole file has to be loaded into the browser first, than the user starts the download.

What do to if the file is 10GB?
Is there a way to read a stream from the server and write a stream to the users download? Or is an other way preferable like to copy the file to a special folder that is directly hosted by the webserver?