# About PDF file opening and downloading flutter web in web hosting

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to generate Pdf in flutter with pdf package in flutter Web.
while doing so I found a solution for flutter web with this code ..

```
Uint8List bytes = await pdf.save() ;
final blob = html.Blob([bytes], 'application/pdf');
final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
html.window.open(url, "_blank");
html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
```

this code worked fine in local host but is not running in web hosting . please help

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not running"?

Comment: Meaning by pdf is not generating in web hosting. but generates while in local hosting in flutter web .

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was deleted, so I'll repost it.

To download files look this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614367/18386517.

If you want to just open PDFs files inside your app try the [pdfx](https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx) package. Here is an example:

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:typed_data';
    import 'package:pdfx/pdfx.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class PdfLabPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String name;
      final FutureOr<Uint8List> content;
    
      const PdfLabPage({Key? key, required  this.name, required  this.content}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<PdfLabPage> createState() => _PdfLabPageState();
    }
    
    class _PdfLabPageState extends State<PdfLabPage> {
    
    late PdfControllerPinch pdfController;
    
     @override
      void initState() {
        pdfController = PdfControllerPinch(
          document: PdfDocument.openData(widget.content)
        );
        super.initState();
    }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        pdfController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
    
    Widget pdfView() => PdfViewPinch(
      controller: pdfController ,
      onDocumentLoaded: (msg) {print(msg.toString());},
      onDocumentError: (error) { print(error.toString());}
    );
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.name),
          ),
          body:
          Center(
            child: pdfView(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I got the content of the PDF file from the web using:

```
var url = "..."
final file = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final content = file.bodyBytes;
```

But you can load from assets (Android, Ios, MacOs, Web):

```
final document = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/sample.pdf')
```

From file (Android, Ios, MacOs):

```
final document = await PdfDocument.openFile('path/to/file/on/device')
```

From data (Android, Ios, MacOs, Web):

```
final document = await PdfDocument.openData((FutureOr<Uint8List>) data)
```

Comment: please tell me where i use this code    final document = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/sample.pdf')

Comment: Just change the PDF controller from "pdfController = PdfControllerPinch(
          document: PdfDocument.openData(widget.content));" to    "pdfController = PdfControllerPinch(
          document: PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/sample.pdf'));"