Error When Compiling Flutter Web Application with WASM Support: "Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform
I'm currently working on a Flutter web application using the latest version (3.22). I've integrated several packages that rely on the dart:html library. Now, I want to compile my application with WebAssembly (WASM) support using the --wasm flag, but I'm encountering the following errors during the build process:
Target dart2wasm failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 64:
*NOTE*: Compilation to WasmGC is experimental.
The support may change, or be removed, with no advance notice.

../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/desktop_drop-0.4.4/lib/desktop_drop_web.dart:2:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html' as html show window, Url;

The errors seem to be primarily caused by the packages importing dart:html, which is not supported in the WASM compilation target. Here are a few of the problematic packages:
desktop_drop
flutter_image_compress_web
flutter_secure_storage_web

Detailed Errors:
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/desktop_drop-0.4.4/lib/desktop_drop_web.dart:2:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html' as html show window, Url;
       
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_secure_storage_web-1.2.1/lib/flutter_secure_storage_web.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html' as html;
       
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_image_compress_web-0.1.4+1/lib/src/pica.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html';
       

Questions
1. How can I resolve the dart:html library issue when compiling with WASM support?
2. Are there any workarounds or alternative packages that do not rely on dart:html but provide similar functionality?
3. Is it possible to conditionally include/exclude code based on the compilation target to avoid these errors?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to compile my Flutter web application with WASM support by using the following command:
flutter build web --wasm
I expected the application to compile successfully with WASM support. However, I encountered errors related to the dart:html library being unavailable on the WASM platform.

Go through with the documentation: https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop/package-web

I did, but the packages i mentioned use the html package.
have you any idea what is the new way of doing this in web package?
final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
..setAttribute("download", fileName)
..click();

You have to wait for those package owners to move away from dart:html to package:web. If you make the changes yourself, you can offer the changes as a pull request, and, in the meantime, just use your modified repo.

@YawarOsman - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783344/flutter-web-download-option/78494363#78494363
