Unable to build flutter web using --wasm flag (flutter 3.22)
When I build the web normally with:
flutter build web
The build is created without any issue. But when I try to build it with the new wasm flag:
flutter build web --wasm
Error states:
Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.

Full error:
Target dart2wasm failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 64:
*NOTE*: Compilation to WasmGC is experimental.
The support may change, or be removed, with no advance notice.


../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluttertoast-8.2.5/lib/fluttertoast_web.dart:2:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these packages:

    main.dart => package:staking_amo => package:get => dart:html
    web_plugin_registrant.dart => package:fluttertoast => dart:html


I'm not using html package in my project directly, do I need to wait for all the other dependecies to migerate to use web package instead of html?
Expected result:
build the web project normally.
Actual result:
error was thrown

Go through with this: https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop/package-web
and flutterToast package is using "dart:html" so it'll not work in wasm. So, just wait until the package get migrated with latest version of flutter/dart

flutterToast is just an example, there are a ton of packages throwing this error, will I be needing to wait for all the packages to even try wasm?

I understand. All the packages using 'dart:html' will throw error. So, yes we need to wait. However, you can look for pull requests on github for each package if there's a branch created by someone says "migrating to wasm or migration from dart:html to package:web" then you can try clone it and try. for example: someone already migrated the flutterToast "https://github.com/a-h-mzd/FlutterToast/tree/master". So, either clone it or just wait for release on pub.dev

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78516000/error-when-compiling-flutter-web-application-with-wasm-support-dart-library-d
