# Flutter Development. Getting data from Firebase Storage and Firestore through Stream Builder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to get data from Firestore Database and Firestore Storage. I am getting text data from Firestore Database collections but I am not able to get images from Firestore Storage. Its giving Exception. I should use Download URLs : To request a download URL, call the getDownloadURL method on a reference. Can anyone guide me where and how I can use it and get images. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#download-urls

[image: Exception]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following is code ;

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: db.collection('running').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              final shoes = Shoes.runningShoes[index];
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          color: Color(0xffF6F6F6)),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                          Image.network(
                            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/shoes-app-e2319.appspot.com/o/${ds['image']}',
                            width:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          ),
                          Align(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: 16.0),
                                child: Image.network(
                                  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/shoes-app-e2319.appspot.com/o/${ds['logo']}',
                                  height: 60,
                                  width: 40,
                                  color: Color(0xffCBCBCB),
                                ),
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight),
                        ],
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment:
                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '\$${ds['price']}',
                          textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        FavoriteButton(valueChanged: () {})
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        ds['name'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              );
            },
            staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
              return StaggeredTile.count(
                  1, index.isEven ? 2.1 : 2.2);
            });
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    },
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs such as `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/shoes-app-e2319.appspot.com/o/${ds['logo']` are not publicly readable by default, so they can't necessarily be read by `Image.network(..)` (which knows nothing about Firebase/Cloud Storage).

You have a few options:

1. Mark the Storage bucket as publicly readable.

   This is very quick to do (see docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)), but does mean that everyone can then access any file in that bucket.
2. Use the Firebase SDK to read the data for the image.

   You can use the Firebase SDK to [get the data](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getData.html) from the file, and then construct an image from that data.

   Also see: [Retrieve Firebase storage image without getting downloadurl flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741590/retrieve-firebase-storage-image-without-getting-downloadurl-flutter/68744449#68744449)
3. Use a download URL.

   A download URL from Firebase Storage looks similar to the URL that you have, but adds an unguessable token to it. This URL then allows public, read-only access to that file. These URLs are the easiest to work with, as any HTTP library can handle them, but it means you must generate the download URL through the Firebase SDK.

   Also see [Downloading Files from firebase storage to flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610221/downloading-files-from-firebase-storage-to-flutter/56611116#56611116)