# how to allow all users to get download link from firebase_Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to allow all users to get download links of files in firebase_storage , but when I send request for a file I get permission denied

here is my firebase_Storage rules

```
    rules_version = '2';
      service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
       match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading Files from firebase storage to flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610221/downloading-files-from-firebase-storage-to-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the "false" to "true" And it worked